# Raspberry Pi fuse (F1) and cpu (IC2) is so hot and not booting, what's wrong?

Tags: power, cpu

My Raspberry Pi was working great but after a couple of hours I found it not booted. then I found out it's CPU and F1 fuse are extremely hot.
I unplugged it and let it to rest for half an hour,
then I tried to turn it on. the red led (pwr) is on (but not really bright and turns off after about ten seconds) and F1 and IC2 become extremely hot immediately and nothing happens. I've checked with different power supplies, have everything unplugged except power and also I tried removing SD card as well but no luck :(

what's wrong with my Raspberry Pi 1?

Comment: Wait at least 24 hours (for the polyfuse to reset) and try with no external connections.

Comment: It has failed.  Once the CPU gets very hot very quickly it is beyond saving.  The most likely cause is over 6V on the 5V line or over 3V3 at several milliamps on a GPIO.

Comment: whoa what you've done before?

Comment: *"what's wrong with my Raspberry Pi 1?"* -> Presumably something shorted and set off the polyfuse: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=polyfuse%20is%3aanswer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overheating and doesn't boot up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92040/overheating-and-doesnt-boot-up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your Pi seems to be permanently damaged.

Either more than 5V has been sent to the Pi, with both the GPIO and the 5v USB input being powered at the same time, a faulty power supply, or more than 5v sent back through the GPIO pins, damaging the cpu and fuse, or the cpu has overheated, damaging internal components. The polyfuse might have been set off, and this is what is causing the issue, although this is unlikely. Just in case this is the issue, try waiting for about a week (so the fuse resets) and try again. I've had this issue with 2 RPis before and I haven't been able to revive either of them.