# Overheating and doesn't boot up

Tags: raspbian

My PPi 3 B+ is just doesnt boot up. CPU is so hot i can't touch it. SD card is not ruined, tried 3 of them, all works even after cooking in RPi. Also it have left some log files on SD card, so it's not completely dead, i guess. I tried not only Raspbian, but also OctoPi, still stay quite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rpi Zero heat a lot ( 200°C in 5 min ) but don't boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55995/rpi-zero-heat-a-lot-200c-in-5-min-but-dont-boot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pi is dead.  The SoC (CPU, System on a Chip) getting hot very fast is a fatal diagnostic.

At some point more than 3V3 was fed into a GPIO or a 3V3 pin, or more than 6V was fed into a 5V pin.